# Word for something made of two parts

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word that has the meaning of something that is made of two different parts. I've looked around on thesaurus and this site for a bit and I can't find anything. Here is the sentence I'm trying to use it in:

> This communication has covered the basics of percolation theory and shown that a 3-dimensional cluster labeling programme is able to describe the complex three dimensional network between the different sites in the **[Insert Word Here]** blend.

And here is an image showing what such a blend looks like.

[image]

The issue is that it's not just an amalgam I'm trying to describe, but a material with two separate interpenetrating  species.

What word should I use to describe this?

Comment: The word *blend* already implies that there's a mixture of materials. If the materials are blended equally, it would be *homogenous*. If they are blended unequally, it would be *heterogeneous*.

Comment: But this is a mixture of two discrete entities. Whilst a mixture of red and blue ping-pong balls is a 'blend' it's different to a continuous mixture of say, water and fruit juice.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Actually, a heterogenous blend is one where the materials are separate, like oil and water, and a homogenous blend is one where the composition is uniform, like salt and water.

Comment: I think the word "blend" itself is potentially troublesome here, in that it implies the two components are more thoroughly mixed together than OP intends. I'd use a more extended phrasing if it was important to convey that the component elements remain discrete at some meaningful level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most appropriate term I can think of is *[composite](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/composite?q=composite)*, used either as a noun or adjective. [NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/composite?q=composite) provides some excellent accompanying examples:

> **composite**
>
> *(adjective)* made up of several parts or elements:
>
> - (esp. of a constructional material) made up of recognizable constituents:
>
>   *a new composite material—a blend of plastic and ceramic resins.*
>
> *(noun)* a thing made up of several parts or elements:
>
> - a composite constructional material:
>
>   *the next decade may well see the introduction of more designer polymers and composites*

Since *composite* refers to several elements, not just two, you could use it in your example this way:

> ... between the *two* different sites in the composite blend

using the word *two* to specify how many elements there are.

The [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54902/2705) provided by Kris, however, is more technically appropriate for the specific example you mention. However, combining this with your suggestion, *binary composite* is certainly an excellent alternative. *Binary mixture* is also technically correct, as all composites, amalgams, blends, etc, are simply mixtures.

Answer (score 8):

***binary***

The most commonly used term in technical literature for something that comprises of two distinct elements, such as a compound ([binary compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_compound)).

Comment: +1 This is it. In this case, *binary mixture* would also work...

Comment: This is a great word for it I'm going to accept this if nothing else comes up soon. How did I not think of this word?

Comment: @Pureferret: I deleted my suggestion, *composite*, because it usually refers to more than two components. Since you're specifically looking for a word that refers to exactly two components, I would certainly agree that *binary* is the way to go.

Comment: @JimiOke *Binary composite* would definitely work though.

Comment: @Pureferret: Hah, that's so true.

Comment: The context already refers to the material as a blend. *Blend* and *composite* are technically not the same. Composites are a special type of engineering materials (http://www.engr.sjsu.edu/WofMatE/Composites.htm).

Comment: @Kris: *Composite* is also used in materials science and chemistry, not just in engineering (usage of which I'm also familiar with, and perhaps more popular). But I'm guessing matsci is the context of the OP's example.

Comment: @JimiOke: In both cases (chemical, engg.), the determining point is that the composite possesses properties not achievable with any of its individual constituent elements alone. This is not true of blends. Also, composites exhibit a distinct interface between them. However, in a non-technical context, we could use composite in a purely literal sense.

Comment: @Kris in this technical case the use of composite fits because "*composite possesses properties not achievable with any of its individual constituent elements alone*"

Comment: Gr8! Then it's simply a *binary composite*, after all!

Comment: The above comment exemplifies why *composite* alone does not specify "something that is made of two different parts" and *only* of those two parts.

Answer (score 3):

The title made me think of **bipartite**, which means literally “having or consisting of two parts”, and is well used in mathematics and biology. Another term that might serve is **bi-heterogeneous**, which is more specific to your purposes; though less widely used, it’s still cromulent.

Answer (score 2):

[Dyadic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dyadic?s=t) is the word you're looking for:

> of or consisting of a dyad; being a group of two.

<sub>source:dictionary.com/dyadic</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like

> the *two-way* blend

Comment: Doesn't that imply some kind of direction?

Answer (score 0):

You've already had some good suggestions, but I'd like to throw in one more: *"**colloidal**"*.

This is a more specific term than *"binary"* or *"heterogeneous"*, and I'm not sure from your description whether it accurately describes the material you're referring to.  But if it does, it's likely to be more informative than the more generic terms.

Comment: Colloidal doesn't fit as one medium isn't truly suspended in the other, at least not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

"[Multi-phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphase_flow)" is the physical term for a medium that contains two or more distinct, inter-mixed, parts.

Depending on your context, the term "[metamorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphism)" may also be appropriate.  The word is principally geological.

Or, just **Aggregate**.

Answer (score 0):

The following come to my mind..

1. Composite (non-metals)
2. Alloy or eutectic ( metals)
3. Compound
4. Mixture
5. Hybrid
6. Combo (edible)